# Contributions Of Computer Science

Tags: big-picture

I would like to know how is theoretical computer science helping to understand mathematics, physics and biology better in our universe. How is it all merging out and how is theoretical computer science helping us to get a better understanding of nature around us? Perhaps some physical problem solved by some unconventional way of using computer science to help understand something in nature that wasn't previously understood well enough/or not understood at all. I don't mean just the application of part of something like the internet for sharing data, but something like theoretical computer science offered a new insight into, for example like quantum mechanics/string theory, some theorem of mathematics or cure for a disease. links to some research papers might be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, this interesting (and wide-scoped) question is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @pvsnp, it would help if you made the question narrower. Even a high-level answer to what you are asking could fill a book. It would also help if you indicated what material you have already consulted to find these answers and why they weren't sufficient.